# Exceeding built-in data type ranges

Tags: c++, types, range

I have been using C++ for quite some time by now and literally took things for granted.

Recently, I asked myself how can the compiler return accurate values{always} when I use out of range values for calculation.

I understand the 2^n{n = bits} concept.

For example: If I would like to add two int's which are out of range such as:
10e6, I would expect the compiler to return a result that is wrong as the bits are overwritten and ultimately represent a wrong integer. But this is never seen to happen.

Can anyone shed some light over this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a situation where you get a different result from what you expect.

Comment: `10e6` is a floating-point literal. It is not an `int`. As @JørgenFogh said, show some code.

Comment: Code: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a = 1000000;
    int b = 1000000;
    int sum = a+b;
    cout << sum << endl;
return 0;    
} /*over here 1000000 is definitely out of integer data type range. Unsigned int range is {-32261, 32260}. Yet you get correct result. @Fogh thats exactly my question. I expect an error because the data at bit level are overwritten but it never happens. */

Comment: An int is a 32-bit integer on most platforms today. This means that the range is much larger - around 4 billion numbers can be represented in total.